# Show $\sigma(x) \in \{0,1\}$ if $x \in \{0,1\}$

Tags: spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $x \in A$ an element with $x^* = x=x^2 = x^3$. I want to show that $\sigma_A(x) \subseteq \{0,1\}$.

Attempt:

We know that $\sigma_A(x)^2=\sigma_A(x^2) = \sigma_A(x^3) = \sigma_A(x)^3$ so I guess the statement somehow follows from $\lambda^2 = \lambda^3 \implies \lambda \in \{0,1\}$.

Let $\lambda \in \sigma_A(x)$. Then $\lambda^2 \in \sigma_A(x)^3$, so there is $\mu \in \sigma_A(x)$ with $\lambda^2 = \mu^3$. Similarly, there is $\eta$ with $\lambda^3 = \eta^2$. I feel like I'm missing something basic...

Comment: Maybe not the most elementary, but the most convenient way to deal with these kind of question is to use the spectral theorem. We can assume that $x$ is a continuous function, and for functions this result is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P$ is a polynomial then $\sigma(P(x))=P(\sigma(x)):= \{ P(\lambda)\mid \lambda\in \sigma(x)\}$.

In particular if $x=x^2$ then $x-x^2=0$ hence for every $\lambda\in \sigma(x)$ you have that $\lambda-\lambda^2=0$. The only complex numbers satisfying this equation are however $0$ and $1$ (as this is a quadratic polynomial it can have at most two solutions), so $\sigma(x)\subseteq \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Wait, is it given that $x=x^2$? At the beginning it didn't appear in the question, only $x^2=x^3$ and $x=x^*$. Maybe OP changed it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I added this later , but I don't think it is strictly necessary.

Comment: Indeed it is not necessary, the roots $x^2-x^3=0$ are also only $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: It is also not necessary for the element to be hermitian. If $x^{n+1}=x^{n}$ for any $n$ you see that $\sigma(x)\subseteq \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to check that $x^2$ and $x^3$ are (orthogonal) projections. Hence the spectrum of these elements is contained in $\{0,1\}$.

So now let $\lambda\in\sigma(x)$. Then $\lambda^2\in\sigma(x^2)\subseteq\{0,1\}$. If $\lambda^2=0$ then $\lambda=0$ and we are done. If $\lambda^2=1$ then either $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-1$. We have to show that the case $\lambda=-1$ is impossible. Indeed, suppose $\lambda=-1$. Then $-1=\lambda^3\in\sigma(x^3)\subseteq\{0,1\}$ which is a contradiction.